# Firebase getCurrentUser returns null after linkWithCredentials Sometimes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm signing up users using Email/Password and Phone methods.
Signing up procedure is as follows
**Sign in user with PhoneAuthCredential > Link created user with EmailCredential from entered email and password > send Email verification > Database entry**

```
public class Sign_Up_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = "Sign_Up_page";

    // UI Widgets.
    private View sign_up_btn;

    // Firebase
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;

    private UserPojo userPojo;

    private String mVerificationId = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign__up_page);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(Sign_Up_page.this, "user is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Sign_Up_page.this, "user not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                mResendToken = token;
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);

        if (v == sign_up_btn) {
              firebaseAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(userEmail).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            SignInMethodQueryResult result = task.getResult();
                            List<String> signInMethods = result != null ? result.getSignInMethods() : null;

                            if (signInMethods != null && signInMethods.size() == 0) {

                                startPhoneNumberVerification(userPhone);

                                verifyPhoneDialog();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(final PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            if (task.getResult() != null) {

                                if (task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser()) {

                                    AuthCredential emailCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(userEmail, userPass);

                                    Toast.makeText(Sign_Up_page.this, "Signedin with phone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    linkUserCredentials(emailCredential);
                                } else {

                                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                    Toast.makeText(THIS, "This Phone no. is already registered with different account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void linkUserCredentials(final AuthCredential credential) {

        firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(Sign_Up_page.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            if (task.getResult() != null) {

                                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();

                                Toast.makeText(Sign_Up_page.this, "credential linked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                // null current user was causing the account to create in Firebase Auth 
                                // but no entry in Database so here I'm using user instance returned on 
                                // linkCredentialSuccess for furthur use instead of "firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()" to prevent that issue
                                sendVerificationEmail(user);
                            }
                        } else {
                            firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().delete();
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    private void sendVerificationEmail(final FirebaseUser createdUser) {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            Toast.makeText(Sign_Up_page.this, "email verification Op complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            createUser(emailDelivery, createdUser);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void createUser(final boolean emailDelivery, final FirebaseUser createdUser) {

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        Toast.makeText(Sign_Up_page.this, "Creating user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        userPojo = new UserPojo();
        userPojo.setValues(...);

        String uid = "";
        if (createdUser != null) {

            uid = createdUser.getUid();
        }

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            AuthCredential emailCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(userEmail, userPass);
            if (createdUser != null) {
                createdUser.reauthenticate(emailCredential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Sign_Up_page.this, "user reAuthenticated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        if (!uid.equals("")) {

            UserProfileChangeRequest userProfile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(userName).build();
            createdUser.updateProfile(userProfile);

            userPojo.setUid(uid);

            final String path = "" + FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(uid);

            reference.child(uid).setValue(userPojo).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Sign_Up_page.this, Home_Screen.class));
                    } else {

                        createdUser.delete();

                        AlertDialog.Builder DbEntryFailDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Sign_Up_page.this);

                        DbEntryFailDialog.setTitle("Error")
                                    .setMessage("Error" + task.getException().getMessage()
                                            + "\n\nentry url is " + path)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                                    .show();

                        Toast.makeText(Sign_Up_page.this, "Error occurred creating account when Db entry fail, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            if (createdUser != null) {

                createdUser.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }
}
```

now the problem is in 1 out of 10 attempts **firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()** becomes null after linking With email credentials
I've added authStateListener to track changes in user Authentication State
here is the screenshot
[of steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HCU6.jpg)

here are my DB write rules for **users** table

```
"users":{           
       "$uid":{
      ".write": "auth.uid != null && newData.exists()",
        },        
   ".indexOn": "role"
 }
```

Now I can handle null user or DB failure, But I want to know and prevent what is causing this problem
I did something wrong or is this a firebase bug...?

Comment: There is nothing in the Firebase Authentication SDK that rejects every tenth request, so it's more likely that something is behaving different in those cases. This is often the result of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). But you shared way too much code for us to efficiently help you find that. I recommend looking at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to increase the chances that somebody spots the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay, Edited the code and I'm not saying it is happening every tenth time, It could happen 1 or 2 times in 10 attempts or not happen at all.
I'm checking current user in sendVerificationEmail() method and whenever this is hapening it is not null here but in next step createUser() method it is returning null.

Comment: Did tou figure out a way to prevent getting those null user values after the linking?